# Catalyst File Transfer sample code

Tags: asp.net, file, transfer

Does anyone know how to use Catalyst File Transfer utility. I saw the site of that product but they dont have any sample code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the samples with the originally downloaded software.